# Flutter webview is show spinner on android but work fine on ios

Tags: android, flutter, http, https, webview

I have a webview e-commerce app when I want to navigate to the webs some of them like amazon will only show home page but it's not load all data and websites like tryndeol just show spinner and it will never end like that:

[image: this is tryndeol website]

it work fine on ios.

Answer (score 0):

solved after adding

```
..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
```

to the webViewController